# Extjs: increase size of a JsonStore

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm working on a software called "Group-Office" which uses the extjs-framework.

I've run into an issue that the so called [data.JsonStore-Object](http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.data.JsonStore.html) has a limit of 30 items. 
I couldn't find any method to increase it in the documentation.

I'd need help from somone who uses this framework on a regular basis or knows it better than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ExtJS store is just a collection of data. There is no limit set unless it has a custom check...

What version are you using? Is the content saved/fetched via a sever? Maybe the limit is implemented there? Can you show us some code?

You can try debugging by setting a breakpoint in the stores add method. (does he get there? check stack trace...)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 
Not really the answer but thanks to you I was able to locate the "limit" in the Controller (was default 30 apparently)
Had to add `$storeParams->limit(1000);`